# I can't do queries with 3 tables in Sequelize (include doesn't work well)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

First, sorry for my bad english. I have a Final Paper to do, but I have some problems to fix it. Always I do a query with 3 tables, some table return null. There is two problems I have:

1. The table *Professor* sometimes returns null
2. The table *Aula* always have the same id of *Professor*, so some *Aulas* can't show the *Professor* who are related.

**Controller Code**

```
static async buscarAulasPorEscola(req, res) {

  try {
    const todasAulas = await database.Escola.findAll({
      include: {
        model: database.Aula,
        include: {
          model: database.Professor
        }
      }
    })
    return res.status(200).json(todasAulas)
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error.message)
  }
}
```

Here are some queries realiazed with the controller above:
[Query-Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fve5.jpg)
[Query-Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZquU.jpg)

**Migrations and Models**
https://ibb.co/album/k4rNgS

I try to realize there controller and show all *includes*, and fix this problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you want; do you need `LEFT JOIN` to handle cases where there's no "Professor"? Then you need `required: false` on the `include` clause.

Comment: As default the sequelize undestands the required is false. The problem is the Aula always pick the same id of Professor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicated `fkprofessor` in `Professor.hasMany(Aula` and at the same time you indicated `id` in `Aula.belongsTo(Professor`.
You either need to indicate `id` or `fkprofessor` in both of them in order to make them work properly and in the same way.